# Is it possible to output a detailed query result file?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new at working with SQL and need to know if it is possible to produce a detailed query result file. I know you can have this file but it only contains info like `1 row(s) affected`, but I need to have detailed info like:
"added row ID,Name,Surname; 1, John, Adams".

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't work like that. You *can* have the inserted records outputted as a resultset using the [`OUTPUT` clause (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017); but you can't change the informational messages.

Comment: @Larnu That is an answer

Comment: @paparazzo it possibly might be, but it's guessing on what the OP is actually asking. I'll happily add it as an answer if the OP elaborates; but I'm not a fan of adding guessed answers. :) (Plus If i were to add an full answer, I'd give examples on how to use `OUTPUT` rather than a link. We all know Link only answers are bad! :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of SQL Server at this time.  If you need this level of insight into your database changes, you could look at using [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) or implementing a custom logging solution (like using Modified/Created columns on the table so that you can query the data to see when things changed or were created).

It's hard to say what your options are without knowing the version of SQL Server you're using and what level of control you have over how the data is getting into the system, but these are at least a couple options.